# Django when I try to migrate migrations to PostgreSQL it throws a exceptions psycopg2.ProgrammingError

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I migrated to sqlite3 to postgresql database and i tried to migrate but it will always throw a exception I am also using drf.

Here is my output:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "django_content_type" does not exist
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 515, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/schema.py", line 112, in _alter_field
    new_db_params, strict,
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 684, in _alter_field
    params,
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/dawid/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "django_content_type" does not exist
```

My `Bucketlist` model has the following code:

```
class Bucketlist(models.Model):
    """This class represents the bucketlist model."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        related_name='bucketlists',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return "{}".format(self.name)

# This receiver handles token creation when a new user is created.
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)`enter code here`
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: My Output Forgot *^*

Comment: When you changed database did you import the `sqlite` data? What steps did you take prior to this change, e.g. 1. updated the settings, 2. db dump sqlite, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these solutions,

1. Either you dump/flush your database if you can afford to. And then try to migrate to PostgreSQL.
2. Follow these steps:

   - Dump your database to JSON.

     ```
     ./manage.py dumpdata --natural-primary --natural-foreign > data.json
     ```
   - Change the settings for default database in `settings.py` i.e. switch to `PostgreSQL`.
   - Sync the database.

     ```
     ./manage.py migrate
     ```
   - Load the data that you stored in `data.json`

     ```
     ./manage.py loaddata data.json
     ```